# BRACKETS in SQL if conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a Rate column in one of my SQL Table where Data is stored.
The data in the rate column , is coming thro an Stored proc.
In that existing stored proc, I found the condition

```
      BEGIN
        IF     @taxPrd <  '07/01/2000' OR 
               @taxPrd >= '11/01/2001' AND @taxPrd <  '04/01/2003' 

          BEGIN
```

I changed it to ...so as to make it true for ALL periods **after sep-1/09**

```
      BEGIN
        IF     @taxPrd <  '07/01/2000' OR 
            ( @taxPrd >= '11/01/2001' AND @taxPrd <  '04/01/2003' ) OR
               @taxPrd >= '09/01/2009'

          BEGIN
```

hence now the rate is valid for

```
              all less than Jul2000 OR
              all in between Nov2001 and Apr2003 OR
               all more than Sep2009
```

**is the placements of brackets correct?**

Comment: FYI: @taxPrd >= '11/01/2001' AND @taxPrd <  '04/01/2003' can be done as @taxPrd BETWEEN '11/01/2001' AND '04/01/2003'

Comment: Sir, any advantage / reason other than apparent ease of writing?

Comment: @recursive, IIRC, BETWEEN is inclusive at both ends...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the brackets are not necessary, (although I'd leave them there for clarity) because the boolean Operator AND takes precedence over the OR operator.  i.e., whenever there is a mixture of ORs and ANDs in a predicate, the ANDs are processed first, and then the resulting expression (with ORs in it ) is processed.

for example

```
 A Or B Or C And D Or E And F And G Or H
```

would be processed as

```
 A Or B Or (C And D) Or (E And F And G) Or H
              \  /          \    /   
               ||             ||                                
 A Or B Or    C&D   Or      E&F&G       Or H
```

Answer (score 1):

Your parentheses are placed correctly for what you want to achieve.

Comment: thanks Phillippe!

I have one further query 

there is an related IF condition just above the ABove condition
                IF @taxPrd >=  '06/01/2005'
            BEGIN
                ....
I changed it to
              IF @taxPrd >=  '06/01/2005' OR @taxPrd < '09/01/2009'

            BEGIN
                ....
I did not place brackets  in this case.
should i place brackets whne there are two conditions only?